# Trying to plot timedelta, but the yaxis is in 1e14, want format HH:MM:SS

Tags: python, matplotlib, timedelta

I am plotting date time on the xaxis (which is actual dates) and then timedelta on the yaxis, which is actually time spans, or amount of time. Originally I was using date time for the yaxis, but I came across the usecase where the time values went over 24 hours, and then it broke the code. So instead I had to use timedelta in order to accommodate these values. But when I try to plot it using plot_date, the yaxis with the timedelta values comes out funny.

[image: Output picture]

I have my information stored in a dataframe originally, and then change the values to a timedelta. This is the code I have to output this graph

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

plt.close('all')

#put data into dataframe
location='D:\CAT'
csvpath=location+('\metrics_summaryTEST.csv')
print csvpath
df=pd.read_csv(csvpath)

#setup plot/figure
media = set(df.mediaNumber.values)
num_plots = len(media)
ax = plt.gca()
pdfpath=location+('\metrics_graphs.pdf')
pp = PdfPages(pdfpath)

#declaring some variables
publishTimevals=np.zeros(len(df.publishTime.values),dtype="S20")
xdates=np.zeros(len(df.publishTime.values),dtype="S20")
ytimes=np.zeros(len(df.totalProcessTime.values),dtype="S8")

for f in sorted(media):
    name = f
    plt.figure(f)
    plt.clf()
    color = next(ax._get_lines.color_cycle)
    #PROCESS PUBLISHTIME
    publishTimevals= df.loc[df['mediaNumber']==f,['publishTime']]
    xdates = map(lambda x: mpl.dates.date2num(dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')),publishTimevals.publishTime)
    #PROCESS TOTALPROCESSTIME
    totalProcessTimevals= df.loc[df['mediaNumber']==f,['totalProcessTime']]
    ytimes = pd.to_timedelta(totalProcessTimevals.totalProcessTime)
    plt.plot_date(xdates,ytimes,'o-',label='totalProcessTime',color=color)
    print ytimes
    plt.show()
    #format the plot
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.xlabel('publishTime')
    plt.ylabel('ProcessTime HH:MM:SS')
    plt.legend(loc=8, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,-0.3),ncol=3,prop={'size':9})
    ax.grid('on')
    plt.title('%s Processing Time' % (f))
    plt.margins(0.05)
    #plt.grid('on')
    plt.minorticks_on()
    plt.grid(which = 'minor', alpha = 0.3)
    plt.grid(which = 'major', alpha = 0.7)
    plt.show()
```

Could anyone point out what's going on here?

Comment: can you please give a sample of your ytimes or totalProcessTimevals, just one value is needed

Comment: Thanks Kirubaharan! The values look like this: totalProcessTimevals = 46:03:11 (which is HH:MM:SS)

Comment: Plotting timedelta on y-axis is still under development https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17553

Comment: @Pimpwhippa: which is great to know, but is there a work around that works right now?